# The correct way to find out the size of an UIElement in pixels

Tags: lightningchart

According to the documentation the UIElement has a getSize method which should return its size in pixels

[doc link](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.3.2/interfaces/uielement.html#getsize)

But when I call this method I don't get what I expect

When I log `el.getSize()` I get something like this : `{x: 5, y: 0}`, but when I log the entire object I see the size field with the correct value:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m39tE.png)

What am I doing wrong?

```js
const {lightningChart, UIElementBuilders} = lcjs;

const dashboard = lightningChart().Dashboard({
    numberOfColumns: 1,
    numberOfRows: 2,
});

const topPanel = dashboard.createUIPanel({
    columnIndex: 0,
    rowIndex: 0,
});

const el1 = topPanel.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.CheckBox)
el1.setText('some text')

console.log(el1.getSize())
console.log('checkbox: ', el1)
```

```html
<script src="http://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.3.2/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that when you are calling `getSize()` the size of the element is not yet calculated.

Something you can try is getting the size after a timeout

```
const el1 = topPanel.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.CheckBox)
el1.setText('some text')

requestAnimationFrame(() => {
   console.log(el1.getSize())
})
```